# How to continuously prompt user for package in Ansible-Playbook

Tags: ansible

I am creating an ansible playbook that prompts the user to enter a package he/she desires but I want it to be able to continuously prompt the user to enter a package until he/she enters 'done'. And how would I be able to install each package the user inputted in my tasks? Below is the code I have that uses the vars_prompt, but I needed help changing it to what I wanted it to do.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: packages
      prompt: "Enter the packages you want to install. Enter 'done' to stop."
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: install packages user desired
      yum:
        name: "{{ packages }}"
        state: installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible really isn't designed for this sort of interactive operation.

One option would be to allow the operator to specify a comma separated list of packages, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: packages
      prompt: "Enter the packages you want to install, separated by commas"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: install packages user desired
      yum:
        name: "{{ packages.split(',') }}"
        state: installed
```

If you really want individual prompts, you could wrap your playbook with a shell script and write that results to a file that you provide as input to your playbook:

```
#!/bin/bash

item=1
packages=()
echo "Enter packages to install. Enter 'done' to stop."
while :; do
    read -p "$(( item++ )). " package
    [[ $package = done ]] && break
    packages+=($package)
done

(
    first=1
    echo '{"packages": ['
    for package in "${packages[@]}"; do
        [[ $first != 1 ]] && echo ","
        first=0
        echo "\"$package\""
    done
    echo ']}'
) > packages.json

ansible-playbook playbook.yml -b -e @packages.json
```

In which case your playbook would look like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: install packages user desired
      yum:
        name: "{{ packages }}"
        state: installed
```